# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when i use a list of tuples to make a graph

Tags: python, list, graph, tuples

This is a sample of a big list of tuples

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_list=[(2496989087L, [114762303, 4046411357L, 3350679909L, 228860861]),(936533587, [1968901658, 2228506255L, 788861322, 3157824057L])]
```

I'd want to make a graph:

```
graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edges_from(my_list)
```

But I receive this error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I don't understand the problem because the list is fine

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to make you error reproducible to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that an object of the `list` type was used as a dictionary key or a set element. In Python dictionary keys must be of immutable type (which `list` is not). To illustrate:

```
>>> D = {}
>>> D[(1, (2))] = 1
>>> D[(1, [2])] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>>
```

You're using incorrect data structure format for [`.add_edges_from()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.add_edges_from.html#networkx.DiGraph.add_edges_from). From the docs:

> The edges must be given as as 2-tuples (u,v) or 3-tuples (u,v,d) where
>   d is a dictionary containing edge data.

Comment: graph.add_edges_from() receive a list of tuples and it worked with another list of tuples

Comment: @Alessandro: it must be a list of 2- or 3-tuples, see the update (and the docs).

Comment: I forgot the real structure, that's not exactly a list of tuples as it should. Thanks a lot